# Python service/framework to run code

Tags: python, rest, web-services

I am having trouble finding an answer to this question.

I am looking for a framework where I can send a python function to a rest endpoint, and it sends a response upon completion.

If there is no precanned solution, what would be a good set of packages to use to do this?

Comment: What do you mean by "send a Python function"? What is the _real_ problem you're solving?

Comment: Let's say I have a method called def Foo(): return 'bar'.  Is there a way to send that to a service?

Comment: ...and `Foo` is not in a package installed on the remote site? So the remote would need to accept a python program, run it, and return the result?

Comment: Correct, that is how I see it running

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try to use SocketIO with Celery.

SocketIO is an option to create a channel between clients (web, mobile apps, etc) and server.

When received a specific message (you can create you own protocol) you can call a task in a Message Queue using Celery framework with Redis or RabbitMQ.

Maybe you need to use an another framework called Kombu to be able to send a message using the connection in socketio.

You can find some tips on this link: http://python-socketio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

I hope I could helped.